# Form contents with updated values, loading with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

When the user updates the form value it is not being found by $('form#myform').html()

Lets say I have:

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text name="mytext" id="mytext" value="1" />
</form>
```

And the user changes 1 into 2.
Then
$('form#myform').html() returns  still; how can I make it return value="2"? I have a dynamic number of form fields so doing $('#mytext).attr('value',$('#mytext).val()); wouldn't be a solution I think.

Hope someone has some advice for me :) Thanks!
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a event listener for **onchange** to all your fields:

```
$.('input').each().change( function(){ /*do sth. with $(this).val() here */ );
```

Comment: Thanks Simon, this will work! There are too many form elements if the form grows to big (unlimited size) to do an onChange- runs horribly slow on old machines, but I will try using the each to update the attribute value when it needs to be triggered

Answer (score 0):

This should work. The problem with showing html is even if you change the text inside the input, the html remains the same. Some you would need to output the current value inside the text field

```
$(".mytext").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

​Check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jz9eU/12/) for example